# Git Deployment to an AWS instance within a VPC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

Last week I succeeded in getting a database and a rails app on two instances and pushing from my console my rails app with a working connection to the database. Now I want to do the same but with the two instances (app and db) safely within a VPC on AWS.

I have the two instances launched within the VPC but I'm struggling to figure out the final step of a) setting up my database.yml to connect to the db now that there's no public ec2 host to refer to; it needs to go through the VPC I assume, but how? b) setting up git so a simple git push production is linked to this rails instance in the AWS.

The only things I've found so far about going about this assume I'm creating the instances via Beanstalk, which wasn't the case. Thoughts?

Edit:

In terms of problem 1, it is now working if I do RAILS_ENV=production rails s, but only with a public DNS or IP; the private ones aren't getting me in. The server ends up timing out, but I've made sure that the VPS is open to port 5432 and so are the instances. The error is:

```
PG::ConnectionBad (could not connect to server: Operation timed out
Is the server running on host "10.0.0.153" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
):
```

And here's my database.yml file

```
production:
 adapter: postgresql
 encoding: unicode
 database: database_name
 host: ip_address
 pool: 10
 username: my_username
 password: my_password
```

Comment: a) try using the private IP b) look at the docs for 'git remote add'

Comment: I've tried the private IP, private DNS, and even added a public DNS and tried that but to no avail. It's throwing "rake aborted!
database configuration does not specify adapter" when I run rake db:migrate. I think I successfully set up the git remote, but until the DB is connected I can't be sure...any more ideas?

Comment: can you post your `database.yml` file ?

Comment: This problem is totes bizarre. I've done RAILS_ENV=production. Yet I can run migrations if I say RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate and I can successfully get rid of the adapter error when running locally if I say RAILS_ENV=production rails s. So RAILS_ENV=production clearly isn't setting correctly...

Comment: Just to clarify, you're running all of these commands locally? Are you able to connect to the db using psql?

Comment: Let's back up a bit. Is your corporate network connected to the VPC? where's your git repository ? Are deploying from a local machine using something like capistrano to the machines in the VPC?

Comment: John - yes, locally. I'm not on any of the instances.

Comment: Is your Corporate Network connected to the VPC? It needs to be in the VPC for you to connect to machines in the VPC. Otherwise you are going to have to connect to one of the machines in the VPC through a public IP address and do the deployment from there.

Comment: Rico - No corporate network to connect. The VPC is newly made and the only relevant instances I'm dealing with are the pg db and the rails app. my git repo is on github. yesterday I was deploying from my local machine to the rails instance using aws.push via Beanstalk. Today I'm trying to get the same rails app pushed to new instances on the VPC that were created from images of the ones I was using yesterday outside of the VPC. I'm deploying manually with git push origin branch_name.

Comment: So, the Rails App is public and that's fine. But it needs to connect to the database which doesn't (or shouldn't and soon won't) have a public DNS. You're saying there's more complexity here than simply messing with the database.yml file; I need to write a script that when I push to rails instance automatically connects to the private db and somehow makes the relevant changes. Just want to confirm my understanding :)

Comment: Well everytime you deploy there's a series of things that you need to do, for example restarting or reloading your web server so that it knows that it has new code. But having said that it looks like your postgres database may not be allowing external connections (outside of the instance, regardless whether it's private or public cloud) Here's a link that might be helpful. http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/postgres-allow-remote-access-tcp-connection.html.  Also, keep in mind that when you deploy to Elastic Beanstalk Amazon takes care of all the configuration.

Comment: Are both machines in the same VPC?

Comment: I didn't deploy via Elastic Beanstalk, so perhaps that would be an easier route. Currently when I manually set it to RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate everything works fine, but that's when using the public DNS. I'm struggling to deploy via git atm so I can only confirm that locally I can now interact with the database via a public DNS.

Comment: Both the rails app instance and the db instance are in the same VPC, yes. I think what Rico said earlier is likely right, that I need to get into the VPC before trying to access the database through its private DNS or IPS. Not quite sure what that looks like, but it's a route of investigation at least.